# Validation in spring3 mvc produces an error

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting this error `Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl` while doing validation in spring3 mvc

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456
```

Comment: I think hibernate-validator dependency is missed. How do you include libraries in your project? If you use maven show us your pom.

Comment: I did in NetBeans,I added 1.hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
 2.validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar to my lib. But I got above problem

Comment: Do you have SLF4j logging library in your project?

Comment: Are you getting this directly in NetBeans, or are you deploying this to another server and seeing the error there?  Are you building a WAR?  If so, and you are not using Maven, how are you building it?

Comment: Thank you very much I changed the server now it's executed. I am very happy.... Once again thank you to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the server. If you are using Ache Tom-act change it to another server. it will work